# Como mudar a cor do texto do VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, código-fonte

Eu queria por cor no texto do vs code, mas não sei nenhum plug-in ou nenhuma maneira de mudar essa cor, me ajuda por favor?

Comment: já clicou no ícone de configurações (engrenagem) e escolheu um tema ("Color Theme")?

Answer (score 0):

você precisa instalar um theme de sua preferência,
Abre o Vscode,
Clica no 4º ícone (onde tem os quadradinhos) e procura por temas! Ex para você buscar: "Atom One Dark Theme". Outro bem legal que eu uso é o "Dracula Official"

- Então você precisa installar o thema!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar novos temas, use `Shift + Alt + X` e pesquise por 'theme'

Use o atalho `Crtl + Shift + P`, escreva 'theme' e escolha um dos temas pré-instalados.